# Is there any way to extract only parameter not the entity?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

I have created an entity "editable" having entries as {name, age, color, place}

bot: select an option to update [options are {name, age, color, place}]

user: name

bot: enter your name?

user: Xyz

bot: record updated. select an option to update [options are {name, age, color, place}]

this works fine

but if a user says something like "*my **name** is Xyz*" to update the name.

bot: select an option to update [options are {name, age, color, place}]

user: **name**

bot: enter your name?

user: my **name** is Xyz

bot: enter your name.

as when the user includes "name" in his phrase then bot matches it with entity and again ask the same question.
how to resolve this issue, I just want to extract the "Xyz" though he uses the phrase "my name is Xyz".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) to handle the flow of the conversation. Contexts are used to help dialogflow detect the correct intent. Output contexts are the contexts created after the intent was detected, and input context is a context required for an intent to be detected.

Think of dialogflow contexts, as the real context of a conversation, there are some phrases that you can expect after an interaction.

Here's an example using 3 intents for this conversation:

- "Default welcome"
- "Updating name selection"
- "Updating name"

**Conversation**

Intent detected: *Default welcome*

Agent says: "Select an option to update [options are {name, age, color, place}]"

Output context: "select-option"

---

User says: "name"

Input context: "select-option"

Intent detected: *Updating name selection*

Agent says: enter your name

Output context: "update-name"

---

User says: "My name is Xyz"

Input context: "update-name"

Intent detected: *Updating name*

Agent says: "record updated"

---

In addition to this, there are [follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) which are used for this scenarios, one of the advantages is that in follow-up intents, the contexts are created automatically.

**Parameters**

You can get all the information to be updated within the same intent. For this, you can add the paramaters as required and take advantage of [slot filling](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#required). Notice that you can specify the define prompts to be used when asking for these parameters.

[image: Actions and parameters]

You would need to add training phrases that help indetifying different parameters given:

[image: Training phrases]

During the conversation, when this intent gets detected, the agent will try to match all the required parameters, and will ask for missing information. At the end, you will have access to this information:

[image: Example of parameters collected]

Consider that this kind of intents can quickly become hard to manage. Try using well defined entities for your parameters, and lots of training phrases (notice that in one training phrase you can collect more than one parameter, e.g., "My name is Xyz and I'm 27").

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the issue is if I use context than I have to make 2 intents for updating each value {name, age, color, place} of the entity. Can you please explain with an example like how to update all the values {name, age, color, place} with these three intents using context.

Comment: I edited the answer. Check the "Parameters" section. In a nutshell, you can get all the information to be updated in the same intent; however, you should be careful as it can get difficult to manage

Comment: Parameters won't work in my case, I have to update the name field and provide a dynamic response and then the user will select what he has to update next.

The solution provided by you will not work if the user wants to update only one parameter, if we use parameter then he has to answer all the prompts for updating a single parameter.

Comment: To update only one parameter per interaction, just set all the parameters as optional.